# Hiding output with rmarkdown knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I need to hide all of my outputs, specifically the plots.

I have tried using this: `knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.show='hide', message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, results='hide')`

But doesn't seem to be working. I'm on the latest version of R

R code starts with the html content here

```yaml
---
title: "Analytics"
subtitle: 'Assessment'
author: "Arden"
output:
  html_notebook: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
---
```

Then the code as below

```r
# load your packages

knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.show='hide', message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, results='hide')

# Load the required libraries (Stopping verbose unnecessary output)  
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))     # Useful for data manipulation
suppressMessages(library(ggplot2))   # Useful for building data visualisations
suppressMessages(library(knitr))     # Useful for creating nice tables
```

All of the code and plots then follows

Comment: `include = FALSE` should hide everything, worth mentioning `echo = FALSE`  too.  https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#package_options

`knitr::opts_chunk$set(include = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)` should do the trick

Comment: Applied that now only my comments are showing. Oddly enough after reverting it's still only showing the comments ...how weird is that

Comment: If you only want the code, another potential option is `knitr::purl()`, re https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/purl.html

Comment: Possibly that changing html_notebook to html_document may help. A notebook's purpose is to show results without knitting.  .. title: "Analytics" subtitle: 'Assessment' author: "Arden" output: html_document: df_print: paged ...